# previous list item as input

Tags: jquery

i am trying to get the value of an input box from a list.  i can get this to work with html like this..

```
<div id='numbs'>
    <input id='1'>enter value
    <input id='2'>enter value
</div>
```

but i cant get this to work if the inputs are in a list.
this is my code. thanks for any help.  im very new to this so if any logic is jacked up please let me know.

```
var lastl = parseInt($("input:last").attr('id'));

$("input").live("click", function() {
    if (this.id == lastl && ($(this).prev('input').attr('value') > 0)) {
        lastl = lastl + 1;
        $('#numbs').append('<input id=' + (lastl) + '> enter value');
   }
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8RpLs/)

edit: i want to be able to make my html in this format

```
<ul id='numbs'>
    <li><input id='1'>enter value</li>
    <li><input id='2'>enter value</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're just trying to add a new `<input>` when they click on the last one in the list.

There are a couple things to be aware of:

1. Use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/), if you have to use an older jQuery then prefer `delegate` over `live`.
2. You probably want to use a focus event instead of a click event. Some people know how to use the keyboard and some have to use the keyboard; besides, focus seems to be a better fit for your intent.
3. Some browsers have issues with all numeric `id` attributes so it is best not to use them.
4. You don't need to know the `id` of the previous item, you can figure out the next one based on the total number of `<input>` elements in play.

I'd use something like this:

```
$('#numbs').on('focus', 'input', function() {
    var $inputs = $('#numbs').find('input');
    if($inputs.index(this) == $inputs.length - 1) {
        var input = '<input id="input-'
                  + $inputs.length
                  + '">';
        $('#numbs').append('<li>' + input + '</li>');
    }
});​
```

You want to take action when they hit the last `<input>` inside the `<ul>` so say exactly that using [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
if($inputs.index(this) == $inputs.length - 1)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/L2MDa/

Comment: Ah, index... I was racking my brain trying to remember that simple function.  Must be time for dinner.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
var numbs = $('#numbs').on('focusin', 'input:text', function (e) {
    var lastInput = numbs.find('input:text:last')[0];

    if (this === lastInput) {
        numbs.append('<li><input /> enter value</li>');
    }
});
```

Also, I switched you event from click to focus as someone may just be tabbing through your form fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without even numbering your inputs:

```
<div id='numbs'>
    <li><input>enter value</li>
    <li><input>enter value</li>
</div>
```

```
$("#numbs").on("focus", 'input', function() {
    var inputs = $('input');
    if (inputs.index(this) == inputs.length-1 && inputs.eq(inputs.length-2).val() > 0 ) {
        $('#numbs').append('<li><input>enter value</li>');
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/k4gMJ/